# How to use different images as form submit button which passes different values to the php page?

Tags: php, html

I made a html and a php page. I put 3 images in html page showing different genre of movies- horror, fantasy, romance. I want the images to work as form submit button and should get redirected to the php page and the php page should get the genre of the image.

What I already tried- I tried lot of different things but nothing worked.
And I wonder how php page will take different inputs from different images using $_POST method.

Expected output-
Suppose if user clicked on image of genre 'horror', then in php page value of $genre should be Horror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `<img>` tag inside a `<button>` element.

```
<form method="post">
<button name="genre" value="horror" type="submit"><img src="./img/horror.jpg"></button>
<button name="genre" value="comedy" type="submit"><img src="./img/comedy.jpg"></button>
</form>
```

You can access the value of the submit button in your PHP using `$_POST['genre']` (or whatever the `name` attribute of your buttons is)

Answer (score 0):

The images should have an href tag that redirects to your PHP page. Note that this method will mean that you should get the value through $_REQUEST variables and not POST or GET. For example lets say href='myphp.php?genre=horror'. and in the PHP file $genre = $_REQUEST['genre'];

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to the following:

```
<input class='genre' type='image' src='/images/genres/horror.jpg' data-genre='horror' />
<input class='genre' type='image' src='/images/genres/sci-fi.jpg' data-genre='sci-fi' />
<input class='genre' type='image' src='/images/genres/chickflick.jpg' data-genre='chickflick' />


<script>
    Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('input.genre') ).forEach( function(input){
        input.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            location.href='info.php?genre='+this.dataset.genre
        });
    })
</script>
```

Assign each input a `dataset` attribute which you query later in the `click` handler. That dataset value is then used to construct the url...

Alternatively a slightly different approach would be to POST the data by setting the value of a hidden field to the dataset attribute value- like:

```
<form name='genres' method='post'>
    <input class='genre' type='image' src='/images/genres/horror.jpg' data-genre='horror' />
    <input class='genre' type='image' src='/images/genres/sci-fi.jpg' data-genre='sci-fi' />
    <input class='genre' type='image' src='/images/genres/chickflick.jpg' data-genre='chickflick' />
    <input class='genre' type='image' src='/images/genres/thriller.jpg' data-genre='thriller' />
    <input class='genre' type='image' src='/images/genres/adventure.jpg' data-genre='adventure' />
    <input class='genre' type='image' src='/images/genres/period-drama.jpg' data-genre='period-drama' />
    <input type='hidden' name='genre' />
</form>
<script>
    let form=document.forms.genres;
    let genre=form.genre;

    Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('input.genre') ).forEach( function(input){
        input.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            /* set hidden input value */
            genre.value=this.dataset.genre;
            /* append the genre to the qction/querystring */
            form.action='?genre='+this.dataset.genre;
            /* go */
            form.submit();
        });
    })
</script>
```